# Equivalent for GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL in Metal

Tags: ios, metal

My app currently uses OpenGL and i set polygon offset using glPolygonOffset and GL_POLYGON_OFFSET_FILL. I am in the process of transforming my code to Metal and looking for the equivalent methods in Metal. What are they?

Answer (score 2):

`MTLRenderCommandEncoder setDepthBias:slopeScale:clamp:`

Comment: Which of the parameters match to the offset parameters (factor and units)?